# CS50 Little Professor 'Timed out while waiting for program to exit'

Tags: python, cs50

I am having trouble when testing my code using check50 as I had tested my code manually before using check50 and it works well. May I know how to solve the 'timed out while waiting for program to exit' bug? Here is my code:

```
import random

def main():
    score = 0
    for _ in range(10):
        level = get_level()
        X = generate_integer(level)
        Y = generate_integer(level)
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                ans = int(input(f'{X} + {Y} = '))
                if ans == X + Y:
                    score += 1
                    break
                else:
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print('EEE')
                if i == 2:
                    print(f'{X} + {Y} =',(X+Y))
    print(f'Score: {score}')

def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input('Level: '))
            if level in [1,2,3]:
                return level
        except ValueError:
            pass

def generate_integer(level):
    match level:
        case 1:
            return random.randint(0,9)
        case 2:
            return random.randint(10,99)
        case _:
            return random.randint(100,999)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the check50 result attached:
[Check50 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBGXs.png)
I hope that someone could explain what is going wrong. Thanks for helping :).

Comment: `if level in [1,2,3]` is your problem since level 4 is no longer valid. why are you doing this?

Comment: I’m trying to check if level is either 1 or 2 or 3 and if it is, return level since it is valid or else just continue looping

Comment: once again, that is exactly your problem. what happens at level 4? you're defining it as invalid, hence you loop forever, waiting for a valid level

Comment: When it is level 4 shouldn’t it be looping again and prompt user to input again since 4 is invalid? And I thought we should loop forever until there’s a valid level?

Comment: because there is infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import random

valid_levels = {'1','2','3'}

def main():
    score = 0
    lvl = get_level()
    for _ in range(10):
        a=generate_integer(lvl)
        b=generate_integer(lvl)
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                assert int(input(f'{a} + {b} = ')) == a+b
                score+=1
                break
            except:
                print('EEE')
                if i==2:
                    print(f'{a} + {b} = {a+b}')
    print(f'Score: {score}')

def get_level():
    lvl = input('Level: ')
    while lvl not in valid_levels:
        lvl = input('Level: ')
    return int(lvl)


def generate_integer(level):
    return random.randint(0,9) if level == 1 else random.randrange(10**(level-1),10**(level))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Here is the actual instruction: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/professor/

Comment: @Pius0405 see the updated answer

Comment: @OM2220 I was so dump I misunderstood the question where it should only prompt level once.... Anyways thanks for helping me ☺️☺️

Answer (score 0):

It works when you test for success! Enter an incorrect answer 3 times, what *should* happen? It should go to the next problem. What *actually* happens? Try it and see. Click spoiler for hint.

> Program should only prompt for level one time.

Comment: But when I had tried for 0 score ( all wrong ) it do works well. After three incorrect answers it will print the correct answer and move to the next question when I test it myself